# How breaks a solid piece of matter?

Tags: forces

In general, when I have a piece of solid matter, it's easier to break it than to pull it apart. Pulling it apart requires breaking all the bonding at once.

Let's take the example of a long piece of diamond. it's difficult to pull it apart, contrary to breaking it. How does the breaking take place? Is my breaking force concentrated in the material somehow? Is there a leverage effect? assume I break it by putting my thumbs beneath it while applying force with the rest of my two hands.

Comment: I believe you are trying to compare apples and oranges. Generally speaking, I believe there is no relationship between tensile strength and impact strength.

Comment: I think questions like this are better fit for engineering se

Comment: @BobD thanks for the reply. I've edited the question. only breaking is involved now.

Comment: @BobD You can put it across your knee and break it without impact and that is easier than breaking it by pulling.

Comment: There are many different failure mechanisms for different materials, that interact with the stress state of the material in different ways. In your second paragraph, yes, there is a very large difference between linear strain and a bending moment.

Answer (score 2):

It is the bending moment that makes it easier.  If for example you lay the rod across your knee at the center and push down on the ends, the normal stress at the center of the rod will be much higher than if you just try to pull it apart.  With bending, the top of the rod at the center will be in tension, the middle of the rod will be neutral and the bottom will be in compression.  Diamond is brittle and a brittle material fails in the direction of maximum tensile stress.

The governing equation to compute the stresses is the bi-harmonic 4th order partial differential equation.  You can find solutions to that equation in any good book on the theory of elasticity.  The one by Timoshenko and Goodier has been the standard for years.

Leverage does play a part since you can apply a larger torque with a longer moment arm.

For a simplified calculation, for

$P$ the applied force at the end

$l$ the distance from the center to the end.

$P l$ will be the applied moment at the center of the rod, and if $a$ is the distance from the center of the rod to the top, the maximum tensile force $F$ for a rectangular cross section is approximately

$F=\frac{P l}{a}$

which can be much greater than your applied force of $P$